# UIImagePickerController weird effect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

app structure: 
4 viewcontrollers in uitabbar controller.

situation:
one of view controllers is actually uitableview controller with add and edit button.
adding new object pushes another view which has text field and option to choose or take picture. picking an image works just fine as it should.

problem:
if instead of picking image, a camera is used with pressing use button, then something goes wrong. the image gets returned and the camera(uiimagepickercontroller) is dismissed which is fine also. but the text fields are now empty (first weird thing)! entering again some values and saving will return to uitablview. now there are 2 rows with same values, and that's the second weird thing.

questions:
how could uiimagepicker controller remove all textfield values? and why its not happening when image from library is used?

how can it duplicates the data entry in ui table view?

info:
i'm using ARC. i dont set text fields to nil when viewDidUnload/WillDisappear.

code:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
self.image.image=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
NSLog(@"did load the image %@", self.image.image);

}


-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
self.image.image=image;

 }

 -(void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
 {
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

 }

- (IBAction)takePic:(id)sender {
[self.name resignFirstResponder];
[self.info resignFirstResponder];
[self.lastname resignFirstResponder];


    UIActionSheet *sheet=nil;
    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
        sheet=[[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:@"Cancel"  otherButtonTitles:@"Choose Photo",@"Take Photo", nil];
    else
        sheet=[[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:@"Cancel"  otherButtonTitles:@"Choose Photo", nil];
    [sheet showInView:self.parentViewController.tabBarController.view];

  }


-(void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
  {

if (buttonIndex==0) return;

UIImagePickerController *takepic=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
takepic.delegate=self;
takepic.allowsEditing=YES;

if (buttonIndex==1) {

    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum]) {
        takepic.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

    }
}
if(buttonIndex==2) {
    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        takepic.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        NSLog(@"entered camerea mode");


    }
}
[self presentModalViewController:takepic animated:YES];  
}
```

> edit:
>   i have found out something "funny" by putting a breakpoint on the viewDidLoad. if uiimage picker source is photo library. after pressing use button returning to the view controller doesnt trigger viewDidLoad again. but it will trigger the viewDidLoad if the uiimagepicker controller source was camera. that seems to be the source of the problem. how to deal with it?

Comment: How do you instantiate your textfields? I think they are still re-instantiated when your app receives memory warning.

Comment: textfield are present on the xib file and i have iboutlet to them

Comment: actually the whol view gets reinstantiated if the uiimagepicker controller source is camera.

Comment: And your textfields are re-instantiated despite you don't nullify them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app gets memory warning. You should store input data in `viewDidUnload` and set it to textFields again in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: is there anyway in xcode to find out about it? my app is actually light weight. that might something to do with 3gs with ios 5.0.1?

Comment: UIImagePickerController and taking picture from camera on iPhone often makes memory warning. So your views are unloaded. What exactly do you want to find about in xCode?

Comment: ok i was confused. i see the mem warning msg in xcode now when camera is presented modally. i have tried to call my "save" method, but crashes the when camera is dismissed. i have to find out what is causing it. frustrating -.- thanks anyway.

Comment: oh well now i have memory leak as result of saving on ViewDidUnload -.-

Comment: shame on me, i meant over released. its getting exec_bad_access. some zombie probably.

Comment: its really crazy! it works properly when enough RAM is available. the app itself uses almost 4 mb, but when iad part is running then it gets overloaded.